# How can I connect Geth to Goerli and view accounts (following Goerli Getting Started)

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I am trying to connect the Geth **Windows** client to the **Goerli Testnet** and view accounts created using Clef (I am essentially following the Goerli Getting Started document, even though the basic instructions did not directly work for the Windows **1.20.10-stable..** client).

I was able to set up two local accounts, though a `masterseed.json` file was never created (I have no idea whether this may be part of the problem).

After creating the accounts, I start Clef with:

```
clef --loglevel "3" --keystore geth-tutorial/keystore --configdir geth-tutorial/geth --chainid 5
```

After the boilerplate output and entering **ok** the output is (note the warning about `masterseed.json`)

```
INFO [07-21|15:14:53.021] Using CLI as UI-channel
INFO [07-21|15:14:53.258] Loaded 4byte database                    embeds=268,621 locals=0 local=./4byte-custom.json
WARN [07-21|15:14:53.266] Failed to open master, rules disabled    err="failed stat on geth-tutorial\\geth\\masterseed.json: CreateFile geth-tutorial\\geth\\masterseed.json: The system cannot find the file specified."
INFO [07-21|15:14:53.270] Starting signer                          chainid=5 keystore=geth-tutorial/keystore light-kdf=false advanced=false
INFO [07-21|15:14:53.861] Audit logs configured                    file=audit.log
INFO [07-21|15:14:53.868] IPC endpoint opened                      url=\\.\pipe\clef.ipc
------- Signer info -------
* extapi_ipc : \\.\pipe\clef.ipc
* intapi_version : 7.0.1
* extapi_version : 6.1.0
```

Note the `url=\\.\pipe\clef.ipc` is apparently the required mechanism for connecting Clef to the Geth Windows client (mentioned in Github issues responses).

I then start Geth using

```
geth --datadir geth-tutorial --ipcpath=\\.\pipe\geth.ipc --goerli --syncmode snap --http --http.api eth,web3
```

And the output is

```
INFO [07-21|14:53:12.838] Starting Geth on Görli testnet...
INFO [07-21|14:53:12.842] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [07-21|14:53:18.058] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [07-21|14:53:18.064] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [07-21|14:53:18.067] Allocated cache and file handles         database=F:\Ethereum\geth-tutorial\geth\chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=8192
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.828] Opened ancient database                  database=F:\Ethereum\geth-tutorial\geth\chaindata\ancient readonly=false
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.867] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=361 size=51.17KiB time="569µs" gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.871]
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.871] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.875] Chain ID:  5 (goerli)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.876] Consensus: Clique (proof-of-authority)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.877]
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.878] Pre-Merge hard forks:
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.879]  - Homestead:                   0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/homestead.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.883]  - Tangerine Whistle (EIP 150): 0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/tangerine-whistle.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.886]  - Spurious Dragon/1 (EIP 155): 0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.889]  - Spurious Dragon/2 (EIP 158): 0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.893]  - Byzantium:                   0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/byzantium.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.896]  - Constantinople:              0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/constantinople.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.899]  - Petersburg:                  0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/petersburg.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.902]  - Istanbul:                    1561651  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/istanbul.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.905]  - Berlin:                      4460644  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/berlin.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.907]  - London:                      5062605  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/london.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.911]
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.911] Merge not configured!
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.912]  - Hard-fork specification: https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/paris.md)
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.915] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [07-21|14:53:19.918]
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.213] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=5 dbversion=8
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.249] Loaded most recent local header          number=7,266,698 hash=01a0ec..5554f9 td=10,626,743 age=15m28s
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.257] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0         hash=bf7e33..b88c1a td=1          age=3y6mo1w
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.262] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=7,266,623 hash=6b4a14..dc7fef td=10,626,642 age=34m13s
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.266] Loaded last fast-sync pivot marker       number=7,266,624
WARN [07-21|14:53:51.368] Snapshot maintenance disabled (syncing)
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.376] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.384] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.388] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.468] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.10.20-stable-8f2416a8/windows-amd64/go1.18.1
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.848] New local node record                    seq=1,658,077,236,613 id=e8a19b4abca60b0a ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.857] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://d43d704ccac522ab2c3abef9c99c47d5b3df57dcfb375c17efeee9817cf99164a362e23247a06565ef1b940e733227b23df6bf2750678558288bb982cdc7f3cc@127.0.0.1:30303
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.858] IPC endpoint opened                      url=\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
INFO [07-21|14:53:51.867] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 auth=false prefix= cors= vhosts=localhost
INFO [07-21|14:53:54.526] New local node record                    seq=1,658,077,236,614 id=e8a19b4abca60b0a ip=10.20.40.108 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [07-21|14:53:54.576] Mapped network port                      proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
```

So far, things seem to work. The Goerli network syncs (now about 103 GB on disc).

I then start another Geth client in another Windows terminal (AKA Command Prompt), and attach to the running Geth and list the accounts created, using this syntax:

```
geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545   [ this is what Getting Started says to use ]
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.10.20-stable-8f2416a8/windows-amd64/go1.18.1
coinbase: 0x7772e3fcaf64575fee5c405f680c863a248e5cdf
at block: 0 (Wed Jan 30 2019 08:26:31 GMT-0500 (EST))
 modules: debug:1.0 eth:1.0 net:1.0 rpc:1.0 web3:1.0

To exit, press ctrl-d or type exit
> eth.accounts
["0x7772e3fcaf64575fee5c405f680c863a248e5cdf", "0x4a40ffd373ace235632fdea9637eebba7e07bf65"]
>
```

The account numbers are correct. HOWEVER, there was no prompt in the Clef window to approve the request (which according to Getting Started, there should have been). Further, when I ty to get the balance of the 0x7772... account, it shows zero, even though according the the Goerli network scan the balance is 1 ETH (which is expected since 1 ETH was deposited to the account from a faucet):

```
> eth.getBalance("0x7772e3FCaF64575FEE5C405F680c863A248E5cdF")
0
>
```

Thinking that somehow getBalance was looking at the ETH mainnet for the 0x7772.. address, I tried this syntax when attaching:

```
geth attach \\.\pipe\clef.ipc http://127.0.0.1:8545 --http.api eth,net,web3
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

 modules: account:1.0 rpc:1.0

To exit, press ctrl-d or type exit
>
```

This causes a warning in the Clef window as soon as the client attaches, and all commands generate an error message in the window:

```
WARN [07-21|21:44:12.343] Served web3_clientVersion                reqid=2 duration=0s err="the method web3_clientVersion does not exist/is not available"
```

When I try to list accounts in the Window attached:

```
> eth.accounts
Error: the method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available
        at web3.js:6365:9(45)
        at get (web3.js:6265:66(12))
        at <eval>:1:1(1)
```

And in the **Clef** Window:

```
WARN [07-21|21:48:01.573] Served eth_accounts                      reqid=4 duration=0s err="the method eth_accounts does not exist/is not available"
```

Perhaps obviously, I am new to Ethereum/Goerli. But this is very frustrating. Given the incorrect initial instructions (and the depiction of results) in the Getting Started guide and hints from Github issues, I conclude that the problem is caused by some subtlety related to the Windows client. But I lack sufficient overall context of the Ethereum architecture to figure out what that subtlety might be - and I am not even sure which of the Geth clients is actually generating the message that appears in the **Clef** console.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance regarding what to do next.
Thanks.